# Help me identify and run this motor

Tags: pcb, brushless-dc-motor, repair, motordriver

I've found a non-functional orbital shaker made by Stovall. When plugged in the power LED turns on , but the motor doesn't run. I thought I'd open the case and try to figure out what went wrong.

There are two PCB inside the case, one is for power, it takes 110/240V and outputs 13.4 V DC. It's connected to the motor driver with a 2 wire connector. The PCBs are not well labeled, so it's hard to tell what's what. The motor board has a 8 pin ribbon connector that connects to a Brushless DC motor. I'm not sure if the motor controller is fried. But if I want the to test the motor with another controller, I need to know the wiring of the motor. There's no marking or serial number written on the motor.

I tried measuring the resistance of the traces on motor cable. The three fat traces have very little resistance between them, I think these are the three motor windings? No idea about the rest of the 5 traces.

Can anybody give me a clue as to how to test this motor?

https://ibb.co/album/cSWhCb